# Boxes seen in Angularjs application running in CEF

Tags: angularjs, compatibility, chromium-embedded

Angularjs v1.4.4
CEF v81.2.16

On viewing the HTML, that is part of the angularjs application in CEF, observing boxes in-place of null characters, as attached. Eg., 90.67/box/box/box

[image]

The issue wasn't present with CEF v41.
Have tried including latest fonts in the Angularjs side and updating loading font in CEF but to no success.

By debugging its clear that the data as part of js is the same in both cases but the HTML view is different. On attempting diff CEF versions similar was observed in CEF v63, CEF v83

Are there any compatibility issues known between angularjs and latest CEF.

Any suggestions or leads would help.

Comment: Did you check the log file? Version 81 is no longer supported, version 91 is the current supported version.

Comment: @amaitland Can you share any common candidates that could be present in the log file that would lead to this.

Comment: I'd usually start by deleting the log file then reproducing the problem, look for any error or warning messages.